# DBSCAN eps incorrect behaviour

Tags: python, dbscan

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
X=np.array([1,9,11,13,14,15,19]).reshape(-1, 1)
db=DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=1).fit(X)
print(db.labels_)
```

prints:

> [0 1 1 1 1 1 2]

while doc says :

> ```
> eps : float, optional
>     The maximum distance between two samples for them to be considered
>     as in the same neighborhood.
> ```

Here 9 and 15 are in the same cluster while euclidiean distance between them is 6 which is >3

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neighborhood is not the same thing as a cluster.

The cluster is the **union of many neighborhoods**. Epsilon is the maximum distance from the center of one neighborhood; but if you merge multiple neighborhoods the distances can become arbitrarily large if your data is *dense*.

But the description of the parameter in sklearn is also wrong, not just misleading. When the triangle inequality holds, points in the same neighborhood *can* be two epsilon apart (and more if you don't use a metric).

Answer (score 1):

To point out why they are in the same cluster, let me give you a high-level explanation of what DBSCAN does.

1. Construct a graph by connecting data points
2. Measure size of each connected component
3. Discard the components smaller than a threshold, which in `sklearn` is the `min_sample` parameter.

`esp` controls the maximum distance for which you connect two data points. For your dataset, with the notation of [a-b] denoting connections, you have:

[9-11], [11-13], [13-14], [14-15]

So these points are all in the same component, and the component is larger than your `min_sample` parameter, so it is considered a valid cluster.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the points chain together. 15 is less than `eps` from 14, so it is included in that cluster.

You can see the behavior here:

```
X=np.array([1,9,11,13,14,15,17,19]).reshape(-1, 1)
db=DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=1).fit(X)

print(db.labels_)
```

gives: `[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]`